# How to make libwebsockets use kqueue() system call internally instead of _poll()?

Tags: libevent, kqueue, libev, libwebsockets

SO FAR: 
1- I have a native application that uses libwebsocket server to communicate to a browser(websockets client). 
2- I see a HIGH CPU usage(activity monitor indicates 100% usage in a 4 core mac machine- Yosemite(10.10.4)) when the app is connected to the websockets client, and we see that the function _poll() is using 75% CPU : seen using Time Profiler Application.
3- So, I configured libwebsockets to use libev, hoping that libev would use kqueue internally, thereby reducing the cpu utilization [ as per steps mentioned in this link: https://github.com/warmcat/libwebsockets/blob/e800db52bd0b42285b56d32a20f6d0d142571a89/changelog scroll down to v1.3-chrome37-firefox30 -> User api additions]

BUT STILL : I'm seeing that _poll() function is getting engaged by libwebsockets.

Could anyone please let me know if I missed anything. My end goal is to see libwebsockets working - using kqueue internally and check if it reduces CPU utilization.